# Deleting files one-by-one vs deleting the same set of files in one run?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I'm assuming that this (batch deleting):

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    updateToStatus1(i, 1); //update table set status = 1 where id = :i
}
deleteAllStatus1();//delete from table where status = 1
```

is faster than this (deleting one-by-one):

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    delete(i); //delete from table where id = i
}
```

Is my assumption true no matter what index I create on "table"? I'm thinking there would be a lot of locking involved when deleting one-by-one.

Also, if anyone can recommend me good regarding materials regarding such SQL trade-offs, I would be very grateful.

Comment: not always true. what happens if you only have one record?

Comment: I'm intrigued. Let's say that in that case, both codes throw an exception at i=1, then could the batch deleting code be faster still? :D

Comment: and what if you set auto commit to false, delete all one by one and then commit the transaction.

Comment: @Shail016 that got me wondering. Let's say in your case we also have an index for status...

Comment: indexes usually slow insert, update and delete queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm assuming that this (batch deleting):

```
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        updateToStatus1(i, 1); //update table set status = 1 where id = :i
    }
    deleteAllStatus1();//delete from table where status = 1
```

is faster than this (deleting one-by-one):

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    delete(i); //delete from table where id = i
}
```

I can only assume that the time taken by first `T1 > T2` (time taken by second )

- in loop1 update(find by id and update staus) is a write operation like delete (find by id and delete row) in loop2
- if you index `status`, update will become costly compared to before (as it changes the value of indexed key).
- indexed status will also have adverse effect on deletion based on status.

> I'm thinking there would be a lot of locking involved when deleting
>   one-by-one.

- That is same for updating one by one also

so your time comparison is between:
`updating one by one + deleting all` vs `deleting one by one`

A single transaction commit for same data would take less time than commit in multiple transactions. But here there is update overhead.

> Also, if anyone can recommend me good regarding materials regarding
>   such SQL trade-offs

for jdbc tips:
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000882.do

[`Chapter 19 Performance`](http://oreilly.com/catalog/jorajdbc/chapter/ch19.html)

for indexes (though for DB2 still useful): [Indexing](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_8.2.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/c0005052.htm?lang=en)

I would also suggest you to search for performance tuning for sql queries and data imports/exports for the DB you are using. These are usually available in reference manuals. like: 
[MySQL sql optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/statement-optimization.html)
[InnoDB performance tuning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-tuning.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think updating the rows one by one will take about the same time as deleting them one by one (of course depending on indices) - so I can't imagine the combination update + batch-delete to be daster than deleting one by one.

The fastest way would be to have a method `delete(int...)` that issues a `DELETE ... WHERE ID IN(...)`.

Comment: Can delete ... where id in(...) be faster than delete ... where status = 1? Let's say in our case, status is a smallint and id is a bigint. Also, let's say there are only about 5 unique values for status. :)

Comment: The point is the time taken by the updates - and delete .. in will certainly take less roundtrips from your code to the database. Having an index on status will speed up delete.. where status, but it will slow down the updates. The depth of the index-tree might have some effects, but to sum it up - it depends, so measure it!!

Comment: are you sure indexing will speed up delete?

Comment: Again, it depends - indexing might speed up finding the records to be deleted by avoiding full table scans, but might also slow down the actual deletion due to necessary reorganization of the index.